# how to display the axes outline when using patch to draw a simple rectangle?

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I'm trying to draw a simple rectangle in matlab with the patch function. The thing is that once I use the patch function the outline box disapear (It seems to ignore the current axes in the figure). This is the simple code I'm using:

```
figure
set(gca,'visible','on')
axis([0,20e9,0.25,1.1])
patch([7e9 7e9 10e9 10e9],[.55 .35 .35 .55],'c','FaceAlpha',0.2,'linestyle','--','edgecolor','b','EdgeAlpha',.2,'linewidth',2);
box on
```

thanks in advance, I'm using the 2013 version of matlab by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that since your patch has transparency, MATLAB must change your figure's renderer from the default renderer to `OpenGL` (which supports transparency). As a result, some features of your graphics (in your case the bounding box on the axes) may appear differently.

If you change the Renderer back to `'painters'`, you'll see that the box goes back to the way you expect but you lose transparency.

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')
```

Unfortunately, there's really no good solution to this. You could consider changing your face color to *appear* to be transparent but not really and then MATLAB can use the default renderer. You could also try to increase the `LineWidth` of the axes

```
set(gca, 'LineWidth', 2)
```

Comment: That's correct @Suever. thanks a lot for the explanation!!